# Internet Explorer 11 Click problem on Xunit

Tags: c#, selenium, xunit

I am using Windows 10 with IE11 on **selenium XUNIT** test. Selenium doesn't click at a desired IE element. Can someone suggest a solution please?

Comment: Try adding the disable `native events` capability to the IE browser caps.

Comment: I have tried adding : DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer(); , cap.SetCapability("nativeEvents", false); I am getting an error that says "internetExplorer doesn't exist in the type 'DesiredCapabilities'. Please suggest anther solution?

Comment: Have you tried `var internetExplorerOptions = new InternetExplorerOptions {
                  IgnoreZoomLevel = true, 
                  EnableNativeEvents = false
               };
var driver = new new InternetExplorerDriver(internetExplorerOptions);`?

Answer (score 0):

We had similar problem back in the day when the change the webdriver for IE, whit this code I can run it only in some computers, because in another's we have a lost of comunication between IE and the driver/code due another problem.

```
public static IWebDriver ExplorerDriverSetUp()
    {
        var options = new InternetExplorerOptions();

        options.RequireWindowFocus = false;
        options.IntroduceInstabilityByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings = true;
        options.IgnoreZoomLevel = true;
        options.EnsureCleanSession = true;
        options.InitialBrowserUrl = URL;

        IWebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(options);
        driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
        return driver;
    }
```